# How to configure `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` with jest

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, jestjs

I have configured Webpack to use `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` for the following.

```
const TEMPLATE_REGEXP = /^template_(BB|FF)(\d{2})$/;
const TEMPLATE_NAME_REGEXP = /(BB|FF)(\d{2})/;

plugins: [
 new Webpack. NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(TEMPLATE_REGEXP, (resource) => {
   const templateName = TEMPLATE_NAME_REGEXP.exec(resource.request)[0];
     resource.request = `${__dirname}/src/templates/template_${templateName}/template_${templateName}.jsx`;
   })
],
```

so that

```
import 'template_ff01'
// will be resolved to 
import 'src/template/template_ff01/template_ff01.jsx'
```

but I am stuck with configuring with jest, I tried with `moduleNameMapper` but nothing seems to work.